# Q: 3D game engine for Android

Tags: software-development, 3d, game, game-development, gaming

i´m quite old to coding but kind of new in the APK and games for android zone, i want to choose the best free option for making games, 3D game preferably. I've done some quick Google searches that gave me Godot, Unity, Construct3, Unreal among others... Any experiences?

make it simple, like if I wanted to code something like a rubik cube in 3d.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The more requirements you give us, the better answers we can give you